# Mule ESB salesforce connector

Tags: salesforce, mule

What is the external ID field name for upsert operation  in salesforce connector. could anyone explain with example.

I have tried with giving any value like name but it is not success.

Answer (score 0):

As per the Mule ESB documentation Unless you configure the External ID Field Name for the sObject to which you’re trying to upsert, every use of the upsert will fail and the upsert operation does not work with the sObject  priceBookentry2. 
The value for this you can find from salesforce only.
For your reference you can check [here](https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-user-guide/v/3.8/salesforce-connector)

Comment: Thanks for you comment, if possible can you please share your xml.

Comment: I have not implemented this so far. I can suggest you can check your salesforce object for more details or you can create an Apex project to know all the details about your salesforce project.

Answer (score 0):

An external ID is a custom field on Salesforce object. 
It contains unique record identifiers from a system outside of Salesforce. This is a field that usually references an ID from another (external) system. 
For instance, if source of your customers is SAP and you are filling account object with these customer records, the SAP customer id can be unique identifier for account object (if you define a custom field that holds this id and assign external id attribute to this field) and you can use this id to update or upsert customers on Salesforce